# AnimationPlayer seek() using threading

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a script attached to an `AnimationPlayer` node and it does some long calculations,
so in order to avoid the game engine from hanging while those calculations take place
I created a separate thread for that function,

but the `seek()` function doesn't update the animation despite adding `update=true`

I've narrowed it down to this simple example:

```
extends AnimationPlayer
tool
export(float,0,1,0.1) var aniTimer = 0 setget aniTimer_Changed;
var thread;

func sep():
    self.seek(aniTimer,true);
    # calculations #

func aniTimer_Changed(new_val):
    aniTimer=new_val;
    thread = Thread.new();
    thread.start(self, "sep");
```

here's how the tree looks like:

[image]

so how to I get the `seek()` to work or is there any workaround with what I'm trying to achieve?

**Edit:**
I tried applied the solution @Theraot gave & modified it to loop through all the animations

like this:

```
func sep(thread:Thread):
    var AnimationList=self.get_animation_list();
    for animation_name in AnimationList:

        self.current_animation=animation_name;
        var ongoing_animation=self.get_animation(animation_name);
        for track_indx in ongoing_animation.get_track_count():
            for key_indx in ongoing_animation.track_get_key_count(track_indx):
                var key_time=ongoing_animation.track_get_key_time(track_indx, key_indx);
                self.seek(key_time,true);

    Translate=false;
    property_list_changed_notify();
    thread.call_deferred("wait_to_finish")

func Translate_Changed(new_val):

    if _thread == null or _thread.is_active():
         _thread = Thread.new();

    _thread.start(self, "sep", _thread);
```

But when I run this for a big animation it gets stuck in between & the entire godot game engine hangs

I'm guessing it's a memory leak?

**what am I trying to achieve?**

I've actually created custom properties on a node and added those custom properties as keys in an `AnimationPlayer`

[image]

but these custom properties all effect `position`, `rotation` & other inbuilt properties.

so I thought by `seek()` I could see the end result of all them combined and then key the `position`, `rotation` & other inbuilt properties to another `AnimationPlayer`

Comment: It increasingly looks like you need an `AnimationPlayer` replacement with a different set of features. Edit: if you need to seek before the computations, I'm guessing you don't have to do it from another thread, do you?

Comment: first part: yes, so that's why I'm making my own custom `AnimationPlayer` with upgrades. Edit part: I don't understand what you mean but I'm using only 1 thread

Comment: I meant that if the call to `seek` must happen before the computations, you could call `seek` on the main thread before starting the one you create for the computations. In other words you could call `seek` in `aniTimer_Changed` and let only the computation to `sep`. However, it appears the Animation panel will not change regardless.

Comment: I don't know what is `old_ani`, so I'm not sure how to test this. However, you are calling `seek` for every key frame, for every track, for every animation. Since `seek` will be moving nodes around, it will cause redraws and UI updates that must happen on the main thread, I guess that is what is making Godot unresponsive. I don't know where you are going with this, but hopefully there is a way to avoid `seek`, or at least reduce the number of calls you have to do.

Comment: @Theraot my applogies, I've fixed the sample code now, Also explained what I'm trying to do

Comment: I see. Yes, that would be a good use of `seek`. However, when you have key frames at the same times on different tracks you would be sampling the same time multiple times (I hope that makes sense). Instead compile the times of the key frames from all the tracks in single list, then go over the list and `seek`. That way the number of times you call `seek` would be reduced. Also, you could have a node do a `seek` per frame. That could be in `_process` instead of using a thread. I think you could even open a modal dialog with a progress bar and does it all in the main thread, across many frames.

Comment: I have tried running the code, and Godot is not becoming unresponsive for me. I guess that is - at least in part - due to my animations being simpler than yours (which also have custom properties and so on). Try inserting a `yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")` either on the outer or the inner `for` loop, that might be enough to keep Godot responsive. By the way, I had to add a call to `stop` because the last animation continued playing after the `Thread` finished.

Comment: @Theraot thank you so much! yield solved the problem! and that stopping animation was also a really helpful tip!

Answer (score 0):

After testing, it appears to me that it works with a couple caveats:

- You need to take proper care of the thread. Which I explain below.
- The change will not be reflected in the Animation panel. However you should be able to see the animation take effect on the nodes.

Once done properly it works on Godot 3.2 or newer. However, starting with Godot 3.4 I could be more sloppy with how I handle the thread and it would still work.

---

First of all, you need to call `wait_to_finish` when the thread ends. Not doing it will prevent proper cleanup. If you don't have code waiting for the thread to finish, you can add this at the end of the thread code:

```
thread.call_deferred("wait_to_finish")
```

Using `call_deferred` (or `set_deferred` or `emit_signal`) allows the thread to issue operations on the main thread.

---

By the way, you can reuse the thread by calling `start` on it again after it finished. So you don't need to create a new `Thread` each time. So you can do this:

```
if thread == null:
    thread = Thread.new()
```

But! The thread will be running for the long computations, and you cannot call `start` on it while it is running. A simple solution is to start another one:

```
if thread == null or thread.is_active():
    thread = Thread.new()
```

*I don't know if there are race conditions to be aware of. Take into consideration the possibility of two threads running at the same time.*

But! that means that when the thread calls `thread.call_deferred("wait_to_finish")` that would not be the correct one. So we are going to pass the `thread` as parameter to the `thread`.

This is how my code looks like:

```
tool
extends AnimationPlayer
export(float,0,1,0.1) var aniTimer = 0.0 setget aniTimer_Changed
var _thread:Thread

func sep(thread:Thread):
    seek(aniTimer, true)
    # calculations #
    thread.call_deferred("wait_to_finish")

func aniTimer_Changed(new_val):
    aniTimer=new_val
    if _thread == null or _thread.is_active():
        _thread = Thread.new()

    # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    _thread.start(self, "sep", _thread)
```

Comment: well technically your answer is correct, & it works but I've added an edit could you take a look?